# Javascript: How to execute command that will affect browser even after refresh?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to stop all videos from playing in the browser so while on the youtube.com page I run `HTMLVideoElement.prototype.play = function() {}`. I click around and since it doesn't do a full page refresh the JS persists.

However, if I press refresh, then my JS is reset and `HTMLVideoElement.prototype.play` once again points to native code. Is there a way to persist that command even on page refreshes?

Comment: May be a `Chrome extension`...

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is run anew on every page load. This is by design and cannot be changed. Use a browser extension or a userscript that runs the script on each page load.

Things run on the console will be lost when the page navigates away (that includes navigating to the same page you're already on).

Comment: Looks like he's running from the console and when he refreshes it, that's lost right?

Comment: Yes. Things run on the console will be lost when the page navigates away (that includes navigating to the same page you're already on)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to persist that command even on page refreshes?

Yes. So long as it's a page you control (so, not youtube.com) you can persist a setting before and after a page refresh by:

1. adding a hash fragment to the URI;
2. adding a query string to the URI
3. placing a cookie
4. using the `window.name` property
5. using HTML5 Web Storage (localStorage / sessionStorage)

By using javascript to query any of the above after the page reloads, you can re-establish the setting you had in place prior to the page refresh.