# Modify HTML in browser, then save the modified file?

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment I have a number in an HTML page. I can increase or decrease that number with + and - buttons. What I can't figure out is how to get those increases or decreases to save so that if I were to open and close the page, I would get the modified number and not the original.

Is something like that possible with JavaScript?

Comment: not really unless you use a server side storage... though you can use a client side storage like web storage/cookies for temporary storage

Comment: not possible in the way you think

Comment: If you want the changes to be visible to *all* users, or if you want an individual user's change to be visible to that user regardless of which device and browser they later view your page with, then you have to store the change server-side. If you just want to store it locally in the browser (which the user could clear if they clear the browser cache) then use cookies or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Why don't you just try local storage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to execute command that will affect browser even after refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685587/javascript-how-to-execute-command-that-will-affect-browser-even-after-refresh)